# How to change the column header background of specific columns in tabulator? (solved)

Tags: javascript, formatting, tabulator, columnheader

I was building a table and needed to change the background color of alternate columns, including the header. I did modify the tabulator.css, and it worked well for the column background itself, but only partially for the header. The main group header background would not change :
[First result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lLyj.png).

I did add some formatter extension as per to [Tabulator documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/modules#extend) :

```
Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("format", "formatters", {
    bold:function(cell, formatterParams){
        return "<strong>" + cell.getValue() + "</strong>"; //make the contents of the cell bold
    },
    uppercase:function(cell, formatterParams){
        return cell.getValue().toUpperCase(); //make the contents of the cell uppercase
    },
    grayed:function(cell, formatterParams) {
        var value = cell.getValue();
        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#93a3a7";
        cell.getElement().style.color = "#fff";
        return "<strong>" + value  + "</strong>";
    }
});
```

And here is my modified css. The trick was to remove the background attribute from the .tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col class, and add an "alternate" class to switch the background for alternate columns :

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
  background: #00b4e1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header .alternate {
     background-color: #93a3a7;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And finally my constructor :

```
function tabulatorGenericClassement(data, tableName, nbOfRaces, raceNamesStr) {
    //console.log(data);
    var raceNames = raceNamesStr.split(";");
    var raceName = "";
    var raceNum = "";
    var colDef = [];
    var colRaces = [];
    var colRacesGroup = "";
    var colGroup = "";
    var isOdd = false;
    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"Regulation\", \"field\":\"reg\", \"width\":150, \"visible\":false}"));
    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"Pos\", \"field\":\"pos\", \"sorter\":\"number\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"}"));
    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"Driver\", \"field\":\"driver\"}"));
    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"Total pts\", \"field\":\"points\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"bold\"}"));
    
    for (i = 0; i <= nbOfRaces; i++) {
        isOdd = !isOdd;
        raceName = raceNames[i];
        raceNum = raceName.substring(raceName.length - 2, raceName.length);
        if (raceNum == "R2"){isOdd = !isOdd;};
        if ( isOdd ){
            switch ( raceNum ) {                
                case "R1":
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"Pts\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"Pos\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"}]";
                    colRacesGroup = "[{\"title\":\"" + raceNum + "\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "},";
                    break;
                case "R2":
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"Pts\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"Pos\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"}]";
                    colRacesGroup = colRacesGroup + "{\"title\":\"" + raceNum + "\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}]";
                    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName.substring(0, raceName.length-2) + "\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"columns\":" + colRacesGroup + "}"));
                    break;  
                default:
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"<p><br/>Pts</p>\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"<p><br/>Pos</p>\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\"}]";
                    //colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName + "\", \"columns\":[{\"title\":\"\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}]}"));
                    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName + "\", \"cssClass\":\"alternate\", \"formatter\":\"grayed\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}"));            
            }       
        } else {
            switch ( raceNum ) {                
                case "R1":
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"Pts\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"Pos\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"}]";
                    colRacesGroup = "[{\"title\":\"" + raceNum + "\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "},";
                    break;
                case "R2":
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"Pts\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"Pos\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"}]";
                    colRacesGroup = colRacesGroup + "{\"title\":\"" + raceNum + "\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}]";
                    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName.substring(0, raceName.length-2) + "\", \"columns\":" + colRacesGroup + "}"));
                    break;  
                default:
                    colGroup = "[{\"title\":\"<p><br/>Pts</p>\", \"field\":\"points" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"},";
                    colGroup = colGroup + "{\"title\":\"<p><br/>Pos</p>\", \"field\":\"pos" + i + "\", \"hozAlign\":\"center\"}]";
                    //colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName + "\", \"columns\":[{\"title\":\"\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}]}"));
                    colDef.push(JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"" + raceName + "\", \"columns\":" + colGroup + "}"));          
            }       
        }
    }       
    
    var table = new Tabulator(tableName, {
        headerSort:false,
        height:1000,
        data:data,
        layout:"fitData",
        groupBy:"reg",
        groupStartOpen:true,
        groupHeader:function(value, count, data, group){

        return value;
    },
        groupToggleElement:"header",
        columns:colDef
    });
}
```

And the final result:
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Dt7.png)